# Reputation on a new site is off between the different tabs

Tags: support, reputation

[Bitcoin SE](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) opened for private beta about 10 days ago.
When I look at the [top users page](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation), I see different values for my rep:

- week - 543
- month (default) - 860
- quarter - 1,173
- year - 1,173
- all - 1,274
- on [my user page](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/78/ripper234), I see 1,274.

Are you eventually consistent? Is this a bug or by design? Do upvotes on my Area51 on/off topic questions count towards my rep?

Comment: I think you've hit the exact border there. Maybe the quarter doesn't start on Sept 1st, but on August 31st or so.

Comment: @Straitjacket: But _year_ should be, well, _this year_, shouldn't it? That's the one I find most stiking.

Comment: Have you check your real rep at http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/reputation and maybe done a recalc, in case something there is throwing it off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values seem correct to me. Presumably you've gained 543 reputation since the beginning of Sunday, UTC, and 860 reputation since the beginning of last Thursday.

As for the quarter/yearly values:

```
1274 = 1173 (rep gained) + 1 (default rep) + 100 (association bonus)
```

The all tab is a bit different in this regard, since unlike the other tabs it shows total reputation, not just gained reputation (where "gained reputation" is reputation not given by default / through system bonuses).

Comment: _Smack!_ The old 101 error ...